# See if an Exception's message matches a known String in Ruby via Test::Unit

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit

Suppose I have a method written in Ruby that I am unit testing via Test::Unit. This method can raise a `SystemExit` for more than one reason, but uniquely identifies the reason it throws it in the `Exception`. I know I can do this to assert that an exception is raised:

```
assert_raises(SystemExit) { boo() }
```

But this matches all cases where `boo()` throws a `SystemExit`. How could I differentiate cases where `boo()` did `abort("reason 1")` from `abort("reason 2")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just trap it with `begin..rescue`.  Write a helper method if you need to do it repeatedly.

```
begin
  boo()
rescue SystemExit => e
  assert_equal(e.message, "This message")
end
```

Comment: Worked like a charm - thanks! Wasn't sure if there was something built into Test::Unit that did this automatically, but this works too!

Comment: You could maybe define `#assert_raises_with_message`, I guess :)

Answer (score 2):

The assert_raises helper already returns you the exception that it catches

```
e = assert_raises(SystemExit) { boo() }
assert_equal("Reason 1", e.message)
```

No need to begin/rescue it yourself.